# Android and toast during

Tags: android, toast

I have toast in method showText(); This method shows toast when we call that method. In second Activity I have a button and when I click on the button my Toast must be shows. Everything work great but when I click two or mnore times my toast will be showing long time. I want to toast show only when I click on button and when I click again, first toast disapear and shows again.

```
public void showText(String msg) {

        Toast.makeText(this, msg, 1000).show();

}
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling show(), you can keep a reference to the Toast you just created

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, msg, 1000);
then toast.show();
and then later, call some methods on the toast like toast.cancel();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html

Comment: This is work when I have this toast and this method in first activity and I want to use that solution in second?

Comment: @edi233 that's how it should be done. but Toast.cancel() seem to be buggy in certain cases and just wont do anything. if you cant manage to use cancel() you might have to turn to another solution (eg: your own custom 'toast'). EDIT: this is not a comment in reply to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way

```
class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnclickListener
{

Toast toast = null;

void onclick(View v)
{
//call showText() method
}

// modify your showText as follows
public void showText(String msg) {

  if(toast != null)
   {
    toast.cancel();
    toast = null;
   }
   toast = new Toast(YourActivity.this);
   toast.setText(msg);
   toast.show()

}


}
```